# how to show Role and Permission OF Current User ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 5 tables:

- User
- UserRole(Junctiontable) contains UserID AND RoleID
- Role
- Permission
- RolePermission(Junctiontable) Contains RoleID and PermissionID

My controller action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //It shows list of Role and Permission
    var ur = db.RolePermission.Include(t => t.Role).Include(t => t.Permission);
    return View(ur.ToList());
}
```

I want to show only Role and Permission for Current User, how can I do that?

Comment: use Anonymous  select new { RoleName, PermissionName } when you to select

Comment: if you can add your class structure then I can write it correctly

Comment: i have tro select it from my table

Comment: yes I assume you have EF classes for this I want to see those .

Comment: Are you using asp identity?

Comment: i am using Database first approach using Entity Framework